# Is Facebook User Access Token refreshed on reinstall?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-access-token

Let's suppose I have an iOS application, linked to a Facebook application. I am interested in the following, yet, the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKAccessToken/#currentAccessToken) are ambivalent (I have no means to test this myself, unfortunately):

Let's suppose a user linked to Facebook through my iOS app. Let's suppose that the app installed is aware of the connection to Facebook (Facebook ID and Facebook User Access Token). So far, so good.

From someone I know I heard that, if one uninstalls the iOS application, reinstalls it and tries to log in with Facebook, the Facebook User Access Token is recreated.

But this seems to be logically flawed, since:

- if the Facebook User Access Token is (re)generated upon logging in with Facebook, then the scenario of installing the app on a second device would render the connection of the first device unusable
- if the Facebook User Access Token is invalidated upon the uninstallation of the iOS app, then, in the case when the app is installed on two devices, uninstalling it from a device would render the connection to the second device unusable

So, logically I assume that the Facebook User Access Token should be portable, that is, after the user uninstalls the iOS app, reinstalls it and tries to connect with Facebook, a function should be usable to gather the Facebook User Access Token, as it should logically be linked to a user, not to a device. Am I right or wrong? If right, how can a Facebook User Access Token be regathered when the user (re)installs the app? If wrong, is there a reason why my reasoning is flawed?

Comment: Can someone tell me why was my question down-voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if one uninstalls the iOS application, reinstalls it and tries to log in with Facebook, the Facebook User Access Token is recreated

A *new* Facebook User Access Token is created. The old token is still active until the user changes his password.

> if the Facebook User Access Token is (re)generated upon logging in with Facebook, then the scenario of installing the app on a second device would render the connection of the first device unusable

Since it's generated and not re-generated it's working as intended. A user can have more than one device connected to use Facebook for iOS.

> If the Facebook User Access Token is invalidated upon the uninstallation of the iOS app

Well this isn't true as stated earlier.

> when the app is installed on two devices, uninstalling it from a device would render the connection to the second device unusable

See above.

> the Facebook User Access Token should be portable,

Correct. The token is portable I can take the token generated from iOS and use it anywhere I please. Of course, this can be mitigated with using an App Secret so that calls can only be made from Facebook servers. However since it's Facebook there are already other internal checks that occur to see any suspicious activity.

> after the user uninstalls the iOS app, reinstalls it and tries to connect with Facebook, a function should be usable to gather the Facebook User Access Token, as it should logically be linked to a user, not to a device

Correct-ish. The token is linked to the user and client (via a machine_id). https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

> If right, how can a Facebook User Access Token be regathered when the user (re)installs the app?

Tokens are generated from sessions. They are not regathered. Every time the user opens the Facebook app and has to login, a new token is generated. Without getting too deep into it, as long as there is a valid session for the user in the device, the new token will be generated. Even if there isn't a session, the user can log in with user/password which will generate the access token and session.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I understand it correctly, the iOS should send a Facebook ID and a Facebook User Access Token to the server and the server should check whether those are valid. Am I right?

Comment: @LajosArpad yes to date, Facebook IDs in Graph API are app scoped so you should check the ID against the access token. So a way to check if your user is your user will be to send to a server which checks the validity in the background.